# Появляется горизонтальный ползунок в браузере (широкая страница)

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста.
[Сайт](http://plutus.ru)

Как сделать так, чтобы снизу не было скролла, у меня все равно справа пустота? При этом чтобы сам сайт (body) остался на середине рабочей области (не был смещен влево или право).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не делать ширину элементов страницы больше ширины экрана.

Вы так сайт пытаетесь раскрутить, да?

Comment: Спасибо, подсказали, действительно не задал там ширину.

Comment: К сожалению, таким способом сайты не раскручиваются...спасибо еще раз, что подсказали, я очень долго искал!